# how to make a Gtk program portable

Tags: c, windows, gtk, portability, gtk3

i wrote a Gtk program under `windows 7` and i want to make it portable and usable by other users in other computers , i tried to just copy the compiled program `.exe` and the required dll , but when running it in an other computer i receive this message :

```
glib-gio-error **: no gsettings schemas are installed on the system
```

i tried to compile it by choosing Debug option and Release option but same problem .

using Code::Blocks

Comment: I vaguely remember getting a Gtk program to run on Window once. Don't you have to install a whole Gtk+ package on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have *all* the DLLs copied *to the same directory as your exe*?

The following is a list of DLLs that, to my understanding, are required to run GTK+ programs in Windows:

```
libatk-1.0-0.dll
libcairo-2.dll
libcairo-gobject-2.dll
libcairo-script-interpreter-2.dll
libcroco-0.6-3.dll
libffi-6.dll
libfontconfig-1.dll
libfreetype-6.dll
libgailutil-3-0.dll
libgdk-3-0.dll
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll
libgio-2.0-0.dll
libglib-2.0-0.dll
libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
libgobject-2.0-0.dll
libgthread-2.0-0.dll
libgtk-3-0.dll
libiconv-2.dll
libintl-8.dll
libjasper-1.dll
libjpeg-9.dll
liblzma-5.dll
libpango-1.0-0.dll
libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll
libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll
libpixman-1-0.dll
libpng15-15.dll
librsvg-2-2.dll
libtiff-5.dll
libxml2-2.dll
pthreadGC2.dll
zlib1.dll
```

Based on my experience, this should work.

Also, make sure all the libraries are linked in the compiler options.

Comment: yes, importing dependencies works, but packing all required files to a single program to avoid handling many files (folders) is better. for further users, if want to pack the program with its dependencies to an installable program (not runnable) you can use **inno setup**.